# Armazenar valores em vetor

Tags: java, array

Tenho um exercicio sobre `vetores/array`com valor simples, onde devo corrigir uma prova, comparando ela com o gabarito e ainda calcular a porcentagem dos alunos que atingiram a média.

> 6) Faça um programa para corrigir provas de múltipla escolha. Cada
>   prova tem oito questões e cada questão vale um ponto. O primeiro
>   conjunto de dados a ser lido é o gabarito da prova. Os outros são os
>   números dos alunos e as respostas que deram às questões. Existem dez
>   alunos matriculados. Calcule e mostre:
>
> a. O número e a nota de cada aluno;
>   b. A percentagem de aprovação
>   sabendo-se que a nota mínima é 6.

Meu gabarito vai ser declarado logo no inicio,ou seja tenho uma arrayinstanciada já com as "respostas"

A professora forneceu uma imagem como ela pretende que o exercício rode

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Meu código no momento é :

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ExercicioVetor6 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

       Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        int arrayAluno[] = new int[10];
        String[] gabarito = new String[] {"b", "d", "e", "a", "b", "c", "b", "a"};
        String resposta;
        int nota = 0;


        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i ++) {

            System.out.println("--- aluno " + (i+1) + " ---");

            for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
                System.out.println("digite a resposta da " + (j+1) + " questão");
                resposta = scan.next();

                if (resposta.equals(gabarito[j]) ) {
                    nota++; 
                }
            }
            System.out.println("A nota do aluno " + (i+1) + " é : " + nota);
            nota = 0; 
        }

    }


    }
```

Mas pelo exercício da professora ela que que eu guarde as respostas dos alunos, depois o programa ira pedir o numero do aluno desejado,comparar as respostas e por ultimo devo fornecer a porcentagem dos alunos com media de 6 para cima!
Quando rodo o código ele repete 10 vezes para eu digitar as respostas dos alunos,as compara como gabarito e fornece a nota!

Porém acredito que falta algo, não sei o que fazer para ficar igual a imagem!

Comment: Array de array, e cada posição do vetor aluno, voce precisará guardar outro vetor, que é correspondende as 8 respostas dadas por ele. Apesar que não é muito simples e nem "elegante" fazer isso. Tem certeza de que é necessário armazenar notas de cada aluno? Pelo teor do exercicio, é completamente descartavel fazer isso.

Comment: agora fiquei mais confusa..como farei Array de Array?

Comment: *"Porém acredito que falta algo"* isso ficou confuso, acredita ou falta mesmo? :)
Se precisa guardar a reposta dos alunos, um array só com 10 posições só vai permitir ter os dados de um aluno. Você já usou array bidimensional? Seria assim: `int[][] arrayAluno= new int[10][8]` ou seja, suporta 10 alunos com 8 notas cada, daí ia poder guardar tudo e calcular como quiser depois. Para guardar os dados pode ser simplesmente assim: `arrayAluno[i][j] = scan.next()`, veja se consegue entender a lógica, senão dou mais detalhes

Comment: Ricardo falta algo..pois não terminei o exercício ja que não consegui pedir nem para o usuário digitar o numero do aluno

Comment: Ricardo e seu eu usar um array simples?
Faria um arrayAluno = new int[10] e um arrayGabarito[8] ?

Comment: Insisto que é completamente desnecessário armazenar a nota de cada aluno para saber a media de aprovados e a nota de cada um. O exercicio não diz em momento algum que se deve armazenar isso.

Comment: Articuno, mesmo que o exercício peça para mim digitar o aluno que quero ver as notas não preciso de array para armazenar as notas?

Comment: Não, não precisa, o exercicio diz que sao dados "a ser lidos", a nao ser que sua professora tenha pedido oralmente que voce armazenasse, o exercicio não pede isso. Voce pode exibir o aluno e sua nota imediatamente após conferir o gabarito da prova dele, seguindo pro proximo, e repetindo o mesmo procedimento. Ao final é que você vai pegar a quantidade de alunos com nota acima de 6 acertos e calcular a porcentagem. Mas ainda sim, não iria ser necessário saber mais a nota, e sim, quantos alunos foram aprovados.

Comment: e como eu faço para o programa pedir para eu digitar o numero do aluno e me exibir as notas? apenas com um System.out.println ?

Comment: Se fizer dessa forma, com array vai ficar bem porco, pois precisará ou de 2 arrays diferentes para armazenar o numero do aluno e outro as notas dele, ou um array como o ricardo mencionou, porém, com um indice a mais no array mais interno, para armazenar o numero do aluno, algo como `arrayAluno[10][9]`.Não tem como fugir disso, com array simples soaria como codigo sujo, ou gambiarra.

Comment: Articuno pelo que o pessoal falou agora na dala a professora que que as notas sejam armazenadas

Comment: Somente nota mesmo? Não precisa armazenar cada questão respondida por cada aluno, correto?

Comment: Isso apenas a nota

Comment: Crie um array bidimensional de aluno, como já explicamos, só que ao inves de `[10][8]`, faça `[10][2]`, onde você guardará em cada uma das 10 posicoes, o numero do aluno e sua nota.

Comment: obrigada pela ajuda

Answer (score 0):

Uma implementação possível com java8

```
    public class App {

        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
            List<Aluno> alunos = new ArrayList<>();
            long numeroAluno = 11110L;

            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                Aluno aluno = new Aluno();
                aluno.setNumero(numeroAluno++);
                aluno.responderQuestoesDaProva();

                alunos.add(aluno);
            }

            Gabarito gabarito = new Gabarito();
            gabarito.adicionarRespostasCorretas(Collections.nCopies(8, "A"));

            for (Aluno aluno : alunos) {
                aluno.corrigirProva(gabarito);

                System.out.println(aluno.getNumero() + " : " + aluno.getNota());
            }

            long totalDeAprovados = alunos.stream()
                    .filter((a) -> a.getNota() >= 3 ? true : false)
                    .count();

            System.out.println("Passou: " + totalDeAprovados + " " + (totalDeAprovados * 100 / alunos.size()));
        }

    }
```

Prova.java:

```
    public class Prova {

        private List<String> questoes = new ArrayList<>();

        public void add(String questao) {
            questoes.add(questao);
        }

        public List<String> getQuestoes() {
            return Collections.unmodifiableList(questoes);
        }
    }
```

Aluno.java:

```
    public class Aluno {

        private Long numero;
        private Prova prova;
        private int nota;

        private List<String> respostasPossiveis = new ArrayList<String>() {        
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
            {
                add("A");
                add("B");
                add("C");
                add("D");
            }
        };

        public Long getNumero() {
            return numero;
        }

        public void setNumero(Long numero) {
            this.numero = numero;
        }

        public Prova getProva() {
            return prova;
        }

        public void setProva(Prova prova) {
            this.prova = prova;
        }

        public void setNota(int nota) {
            this.nota = nota;
        }

        public int getNota() {
            return nota;
        }

        public void verQuestoesRespondidas() {
            prova.getQuestoes().forEach((q) -> System.out.print(q));
        }

        public void responderQuestoesDaProva() {
            prova = new Prova();
            for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
                Collections.shuffle(respostasPossiveis);

                prova.add(respostasPossiveis.stream()
                        .findFirst()
                        .get());
            }
        }

        public void corrigirProva(Gabarito gabarito) {
            List<String> respostasCorretas = gabarito.getRespostas();
            List<String> questoesRespondidas = prova.getQuestoes();

            for (int i = 0;i < respostasCorretas.size(); i++) {
                if(respostasCorretas.get(i).equals(questoesRespondidas.get(i))) nota++;
            }
        }

    }
```

Gabarito.java:

```
    public class Gabarito {

        private List<String> respostas;

        public List<String> getRespostas() {
            return Collections.unmodifiableList(respostas);
        }

        public void adicionarRespostasCorretas(List<String> respostas) {
             this.respostas = respostas;

        }
    }
```

Comment: Java 8 ou superior

Comment: Seria interessante colocar uma forma com versoes inferiores tambem, o autor pode nao utilizar o java 8.

Comment: @Articuno Beleza, vou editar mais tarde pra adicionar um código sem os recursos do java 8